# Javascript AJAX function not loading

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I had a realtivley simple ajax application, which I have broken up to be more modular. The code is at the link below, and what I have mainly done is add the GetRecordSet function and allowed fetchcompelte to take a variable for which layer to put data in. It should work fine in thery. When I put alert()s in, the code seems to execute, except for inside either of the if clauses in fetchcomplete.

http://www.nomorepasting.com/getpaste.php?pasteid=22558

This is the code for get_records.php, which again seems like it should be fine

http://www.nomorepasting.com/getpaste.php?pasteid=22559

and this is the original index php file

http://www.nomorepasting.com/getpaste.php?pasteid=22560

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firsly I would agree with Shyam and also install Firebug for Firefox; this will be a huge help for javascript debugging.

anyway, the line

```
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = FetchComplete(layername);
```

will assign the result of `FetchComplete(layername)` to `xmlHttp.onreadystatechange`, which isn't what you want. It would need to be

```
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = FetchComplete;
```

But then you have the problem of passing `layername`.

If you define the onreadystatechange as an anonymous inner function you can easily use variables defined outside it, so you could do something like this:

```
function GetAuctionData(pk) {

    var xmlHttp=GetXmlHttpObject();
    var layer = "Layer2";

    if(xmlHttp==null) {
        alert("Your browser is not supported?");
    }

    var url="get_auction.php?";
    url=url+"cmd=GetAuctionData&pk="+pk;
    url=url+"&sid="+Math.random();

    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(xmlHttp.readyState==4 || xmlHttp.readyState=="complete") {
            document.getElementById(layer).innerHTML=xmlHttp.responseText
        } else if (xmlHttp.readyState==1 || xmlHttp.readyState=="loading") {
            document.getElementById(layer).innerHTML="loading"
        }
    };

    xmlHttp.open("GET",url,true)
    xmlHttp.send(null)
}
```

`layer` is defined as a local variable in GetAuctionData() but is accessible in the anonymous function, because you are creating a Closure. Note that I haven't tested the above function, but it should work in principle.

Comment: Hi Tom, that works fine, I am just wondering if there is a more efficient way than declaring the same inner function for each method? Perhaps passing the url and such as variables is a better approach?

Comment: Surely the inner function will be different for each method? Also if you used something like prototype you could do the whole lot on one line, e.g. new Ajax.Updater(layer, url);

Comment: I have GetAuctionData and GetRecordSet which are basically the same, except for the php file they call and parameters passed. they both have the same inner function at present. I know about frameworks but enjoy ironing out the kins at the moment.

Comment: then you could make a function like update(layer, url) and use that function twice.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you use prototypejs from [http://www.prototypejs.org](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/ajax/request), which would abstract all the status checks in your code and make it simpler and get rid of the mess.

If for some reason you prefer to use your own code then avoid using string values for the readyState property of the XMLHttpRequestObject. Use the following table instead

```
 State Description 
   0   The request is not initialized 
   1   The request has been set up 
   2   The request has been sent 
   3   The request is in process 
   4   The request is complete
```

and check.